# Java Spring MVC Hibernate OpenSessionInView configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to add OpenSessionInView feature of hibernate because I access to Lazy OneToMany association in my template. (I don't found out another option to avoid the Lazy-Exception)

Initially I did not have an applicationContext.xml but only the *-servlet.xml. I think the OpenSessionInView needs the ContextLoaderListener which requires the applicationContext.xml?

When I want to deploy the app I get the following output in the console:

```
04-Apr-2016 12:34:54.659 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
04-Apr-2016 12:34:54.740 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Apr 04 12:34:54 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
04-Apr-2016 12:34:54.778 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
04-Apr-2016 12:34:55.083 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
04-Apr-2016 12:34:55.085 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
04-Apr-2016 12:34:55.086 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
04-Apr-2016 12:34:55.205 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
04-Apr-2016 12:34:55.508 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
04-Apr-2016 12:34:55.870 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit> HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.0.Final
04-Apr-2016 12:34:56.294 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@7e9ba] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
04-Apr-2016 12:34:56.304 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1643 ms
04-Apr-2016 12:34:56.314 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
04-Apr-2016 12:34:56.314 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
04-Apr-2016 12:34:56.317 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Apr 04 12:34:54 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
04-Apr-2016 12:34:56.319 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(29)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2016-04-04 12:34:56,827] Artifact myapp:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

My web.xml looks like

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

My springdispatcher-servlet.xml looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

    <bean id="freemarkerConfig"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And finally the applicationContext.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mypackage" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**EDIT**: I have no idea why but after moving these lines to the applicationContext.xml it worked:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

But I will not mark my question as solved because I think that this is not the clean solution.

Comment: Do you have a hibernate config file?

Comment: I've only had minimal experience with hibernate and spring, but I had a hibernate configuration file which usually looks something like hibernate.cfg.xml. This would be where you list all your jdbc driver properties. You also map your classes here so that it knows which ones match up to the database. In my particular case, I didn't need an applicationContext.xml so I can't really speak about your need. I think a configuration file may help you though.

Comment: Use the `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` instead. Configure it like any other interceptor and ditch the filter, then you don't need a `ContextLoaderListener`. However you also appear to have Spring Security which also requires a `ContextLoaderListener` registered. I suspect that your component-scanning detects your security configuration and fixing that, fixes the startup of your application.

Comment: Yes, I configured spring security with Java Code (not xml).